# Wiremock: HTTP Web Site Testing without UI

Tags: java, integration-testing, wiremock

I"m given a requirement on how to test HTTP website without UI. Let says, we have a google website search functionalities (Not Web Services) and I need to test it. How to start? Can anyone give some example (JUnit)(Get/Post Method) for me to start this project. I tried reading the official documentation but found nothing about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following snippet

```
public class Searcher {

    public String search(String searchUrl, String searchWord) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(searchUrl);
            builder.setParameter("search_term", searchWord);

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(builder.build());
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);

            return convertResponseToString(httpResponse);
        }
    }

    private String convertResponseToString(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8")) {
            String responseString = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

            return responseString;
        }
    }
}

public class SearcherTest {

    @Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(options().dynamicPort());

    @Test
    public void searchTest() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        String searchWord = "something";
        String expectedResult = "Your expected result";

        stubFor(get(urlPathEqualTo("/search"))
            .withQueryParam("search_term", equalTo(searchWord))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withBody(expectedResult)));

        Searcher searcher = new Searcher();
        String searchResult = searcher.search("http://localhost:" + wireMockRule.port() + "/search", searchWord);

        verify(getRequestedFor(urlPathEqualTo("/search"))
            .withQueryParam("search_term", equalTo(searchWord)));
        assertEquals(expectedResult, searchResult);
}
```

}

Comment: I understand that. But when your code calling the search url you must pass in something like "http://localhost:" + wireMockRule.port() + "/whateveryouwant" then you can stub this search and give a response like my example

Comment: I need more full detailed example from rule setup to stub coding.

Comment: You really a helpful person. Thanks very much. I don't see any URL request to google site. verify(getRequestedFor(urlPathEqualTo("/search"))
            .withQueryParam("search_term", equalTo(searchWord)));

Comment: This type of test replace Selenium browser and test using http method get post. Am i right?

Comment: You can do it also with selenium tests. This is only a sample who made a GET-Request from the Java code.

For your first question, in my example you must define on which URL the Stub listening to. In my example it listen to requests on "/search".
Then you must pass the url to the component which makes the search call.